# Qt: How to make custom widget that aligns like QTextField

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit, qlayout

I am trying to make a `DirectoryEditWidget`, i.e. a widget similar to a `QLineEdit` widget, but with a browse-button to allow the user to browse the file system for the directory.
The functionality is working in the implementation below, but I would like a solution that will snap into a `QFormLayout` and line up nicely with everything else.

[image]

```
class FileEditWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """
    A textfield with a browse button.

    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.file_line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.file_line_edit, stretch=1)
        browse_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("...")
        layout.addWidget(browse_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        browse_button.clicked.connect(self.browse)

    def browse(self, msg = None, start_path = None):
        directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
            msg or "Find files", start_path or QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
        if directory:
            self.file_line_edit.setText(directory)
```

I suspect, I will have to modify the layout properties of the parent `QWidget` object or the layout -- but I don't have much of an idea where to start?

In the screenshot below, I have included my custom widget like so:

```
def create_form_group(self):
    form_group_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Central widget with form layout")
    layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
    layout.addRow(QLabel("Name of stuff"), QtWidgets.QLineEdit())
    layout.addRow(QLabel("Folder name"), FileEditWidget())
    layout.addRow(QLabel("Some selection"), QtWidgets.QComboBox())
```

Comment: All widgets have customisable content margins on each side. Top, bottom, left and right. They have some small value by default which is why you see a slight indent on all sides on your FileEditWidget. Make a call to the python equivilent of setContentsMargins( leftMargin, topMargin,  rightMargin, bottomMargin ) on your FileEditWidget, replacing in the values you want (try 0 for the left and right margins) and it should align properly. Also note that all Qt layouts have the exact same concept, though I don't believe they have any margins set by default.

Comment: My mistake it is the layouts that have the default margins, not the widgets :) The answer below points it out excellently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the margins of the layout.

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins):

> By default, QLayout uses the values provided by the style. On most
>   platforms, the margin is 11 pixels in all directions.

In the following image I show these margins:

[image]

To remove them use this in FileEditWidget.

```
class FileEditWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        [...]
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

[image]